# How do I configure status notification color settings in byobu?

Tags: byobu

How do I set the background and foreground for the status notifications individually?

For example, specifically for **LOGO** or **memory**?

Can I tweak them individually in *~/.byobu/color* somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to edit the scripts individually in `/usr/lib/byobu/*`, if you want to modify their background and foreground colors.

Alternatively, you can add your own custom notification scripts, with your own color choices in `~/.byobu/bin/*`.  You could copy those that you want to modify from `/usr/lib/byobu/*` to `~/.byobu/bin/*` and update them accordingly.

See the manpage, [byobu.1](http://manpg.es/byobu.1) for the details on how to configure a custom status script.

Comment: +1 this is hacking-around a little more than I usually like, but it seems possible to infer how to do this: I tried `logo` first, taking care to experiment with the `color m W; printf "%s" "$LOGO"; color -` calls, using F5 to refresh as I go along.  At the very least, I will learn how to customise byobu in the future, should I need to.  ty.